# Out of Stack Space in IE 10 64-bit. Registry tweak?

Tags: internet-explorer, 64-bit, out-of-memory, internet-explorer-10, gxt

I'm working on a GXT application that crashes with an Out Of Stack Space error in IE 10 64 bit (because 32 bit IE runs out of addressable memory) while attempting to display an extremely large data set in a tree control. This isn't a stack overflow; it's hitting a memory limit rather than recursion limit. I've researched multiple options (including fundamentally re-designing the app), but memory usage is mostly outside our control and I haven't been able to get much traction behind better solutions.

So, while inevitable suggestions that we're doing something fundamentally wrong are appreciated, acknowledged and welcomed, I'd like to primarily ask if there is an IE registry entry that can be tweaked to increase the artificial stack space limit I seem to be running into. Note that my system has sufficient RAM; I'm running into a software limit.

Answer (score 0):

The default stack size for new threads is embedded in the .exe file (see the "size of stack" fields in the dump output below). When creating threads, an application *can* specify a custom stack size, but most applications just use the default specified at compile time.

```
>link.exe /dump /headers "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" 

Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 11.00.50727.1 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

...    

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             20B magic # (PE32+)
           10.00 linker version
            4A00 size of code
           B1C00 size of initialized data
               0 size of uninitialized data
            2CE8 entry point (0000000000402CE8) wWinMainCRTStartup
            1000 base of code
          400000 image base (0000000000400000 to 00000000004BAFFF)
            1000 section alignment
             200 file alignment
            6.01 operating system version
            6.01 image version
            6.00 subsystem version
               0 Win32 version
           BB000 size of image
             400 size of headers
           C16C7 checksum
               2 subsystem (Windows GUI)
            8140 DLL characteristics
                   Dynamic base
                   NX compatible
                   Terminal Server Aware
          100000 size of stack reserve
            E000 size of stack commit
```

It is possible to edit these, but you have to copy the entire directory to sidestep some of the security restrictions. Using the visual studio toolset, this will double the stack size:

1. Copy: "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" to "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer Big"
2. Run: editbin.exe /STACK:0x200000,0xE000 "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer Big\iexplore.exe"

For reference, the PE file format specification can be download [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx).

Comment: Internet Explorer *does* set the stack size explicitly for JavaScript threads.

Comment: EricLaw, is this configurable via registry?